# Properties of extendable irreducible characters to a normal Sylow subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, character-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group with a nilpotent commutator subgroup, and denote by $mcd(G)$ the set of degrees of the irreducible monomial characters. Suppose $|mcd(g)|=2$. Furthermore, we call a monomial character "good" if it induced from a subgroup $H<G$ so that there exists $\psi\in Irr(H)$ with $$gcd(\chi(1),\psi(1))>1$$
I have proved the following: 
If all irreducible monomial characters of $G$ are good, then $G$ is metabelian (that is $G''=1$). As @Tobias Kildetoft made me aware of, if $G$ does not have a good monomial irreducible character then $G$ need not be metabelian.

However, I want to improve this result. If for example $G$ does not have a good irreducible monomial character, but there exists some $\psi\in Irr(G)$ with $$gcd(\chi(1),\psi(1))=1$$ then $\psi$ extends to a normal Sylow subgroup. I know that in this case, $G$ need still not be metabelian, but it certainly is close. I am therefore looking for some results on extendable characters to add a small extra assumption on $G$ to show that it is metabelian. The results in M. Isaac's "Character Theory of Finite Groups" are to no particular help. Does anyone know of some nice theorems in this direction? If it helps, $\psi$ in my case can be assumed to be faithful.